# Can a Cloud Function read from Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

The only docs I can find about using GCF+GCS is https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage. AFAICT this is just showing how to use GCS events to trigger GCF.

In the docs for [GCF dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/dependencies), it only mentions node modules. Is it possible for GCF code to read from a GCS bucket? Is it simply the case of requiring a node module that knows how to communicate with GCS and if so, are there any examples of that?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, but note that it will store the result in a ramdisk, so you'll need enough RAM available to your function to download the file.

```node
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  const gcs = storage({projectId: "<your_project>"});
  const bucket = gcs.bucket("<your_bucket>");
  const file = bucket.file("<path/to/your_file>")
    
  exports.gcstest = (event, callback) => {
    file.download({destination:"/tmp/test"}, function(err, file) {
      if (err) {console.log(err)}
        else{callback();}
    })
  };
```

Comment: Is `fs` intentionally unused?

Comment: I sincerely don't know why I thought that importing `fs` would be needed. It's an old GCF test I did precisely to answer myself the same question you asked, and I guess I tried several approaches before reaching the current one. I'll edit the import out.

Comment: Also, don't trust that it'll work. As far as I can remember, it ended up working, but it's an old one. Better try it yourself. Also also, in this case is pubsub-triggered. Change if needed.

Comment: Thanks. My use case will also be pubsub-triggered.

Comment: OK, just re-deployed the function and it still works (even without `fs`!). My personal version also checks the time it takes to download, as I was curious about the throughput. Let me know if you're also interested and I can update the example with my more complete one.

Answer (score 3):

Google cloud functions will just execute the code you uploaded.
If your code includes libraries to connect to google cloud storage, then, you will be able to connect to google cloud storage, as you will connect to any other api / service.

There are several ways to connect to google cloud storage, like API , oauth, or signed urls ... All these methods are usable on google cloud functions, so I would recommend you have a look at google cloud storage documentation to find the best way for your case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can read and write to storage bucket

```js
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');
const file = myBucket.file('my-file');

file.createReadStream().on('data', () => {
    // do something!
});
```

for more information check the documentations on [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.3.x/File#createReadStream).