# Google Cloud Function - read the CONTENT of a new file created a bucket using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, function, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, bucket

In GCP (not firebase) I have a bucket and a function which will be called when a new file was created in the bucket. Works great.

```
/**
 * Triggered from a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
 */
exports.mycompany_upload_file = (event, context) => {
    const gcsEvent = event;
    const filename = gcsEvent.name;
    const bucketName = event.bucket;
    console.log(`=====================================================`);
    console.log(`Event Type: ${context.eventType}`);
    console.log(`Bucket:     ${bucketName}`);
    console.log(`Datei:      ${filename}`);
    console.log(`=====================================================`);

    // now I would like to open that file and read it line-by-line
```

How do I address that file? What's the path of that file?
Can I use standard node libraries like 'fs'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201011/can-a-cloud-function-read-from-cloud-storage) that might help you, but looks like basically the answer is as follows:

Note that it will store the result in a ramdisk, so you'll need enough RAM available to your function to download the file.

```
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const gcs = storage({projectId: "<your_project>"});
const bucket = gcs.bucket("<your_bucket>");
const file = bucket.file("<path/to/your_file>")

exports.gcstest = (event, callback) => {
  file.download({destination:"/tmp/test"}, function(err, file) {
    if (err) {console.log(err)}
    else{callback();}
  })
};
```

For more information you can check the documentation for [Google Cloud Storage: Node.js Client](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/#createReadStream)

Comment: I hoped there's a way to directly read the file in the bucket without making a copy to (ram) disk

Comment: Any processing must be done in RAM somewhere, Cloud Storage is not a solution to perform computation, if you check the [features of the tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage#all-features) it does not include processing.